TS2344: type inferred from property on generic argument "does not satisfy the constraint" even though the type seems to work fine?
I have an inheritance chain similar to this (fictional names - I realize they are not perfect):
interface Vehicle {}
interface Airplane extends Vehicle {
  number: number;
}
interface Boat extends Vehicle {
  color: string;
}
interface Workshop<TVehicle extends Vehicle = Vehicle> {
  vehicleType: TVehicle;
  repair: (vehicle: TVehicle) => WorkOrder<this>;
}
interface WorkOrder<TWorkshop extends Workshop<TWorkshop["vehicleType"]>> {
  vehicle: TWorkshop["vehicleType"];
}

The idea is that the type of a WorkOrder.vehicle should be inferrable based on the Workshop provided as a type argument:
const orderA: WorkOrder<Workshop<Airplane>> = {
  vehicle: {
    number: 123,
  },
};

const orderB: WorkOrder<Workshop<Boat>> = {
  vehicle: {
    color: "blue",
  },
};

This actually works! I receive editor completion for the above examples and the following produces an error:
const orderA: WorkOrder<Workshop<Airplane>> = {
  vehicle: {
    color: "blue", // ERROR! Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'color' does not exist in type 'Airplane'
  },
};

BUT - I get an error on the type argument TWorkshop["vehicleType"] inside the generic argument for WorkOrder:
Type 'TWorkshop["vehicleType"]' does not satisfy the constraint 'Vehicle'.ts(2344)

I don't understand why, nor why the constraint actually seems to work given the complaint - can anyone explain what is going on?

Edit: Link to TS Playground

It's ms/TS#49490, but it hasn't been classified as a bug or a design limitation or even working as intended (and it's not new, so who knows if/when it will ever be triaged). You have a circular constraint and TS is having trouble validating it. Would you accept that as an answer? Or do you need to see ms/TS#49490 triaged before accepting an answer?

@jcalz it seemed like a bug to me (given that the type actually worked as expected if the warning was ignored) so yes, I would accept that as an answer. If you have any insight on the safety of using @ts-ignore on this, that would be extra appreciated!

I doubt //@ts-ignore will break anything but I generally avoid that. I'd much rather any, which is an intentional loosening of the type system, as opposed to //@ts-ignore which is a "pretend there's no error" directive. But that's just opinion and probably out of scope here.

I’ll write up an answer when I get a chance, btw

This looks like the same issue reported in microsoft/TypeScript#49490, caused by a change in microsoft/TypeScript#49119 released in TypeScript 4.8 to improve reduction of intersection types. It isn't clear whether this is considered a bug, a design limitation, or working as intended.  Your generic constraint is circular, and so you can't necessarily expect such things to work as desired.

That's the answer to the question as asked. But presumably you want to know how to fix it also.
You could force TypeScript to see that your type argument meets the Vehicle constraint, by intersecting it with Vehicle:
interface WorkOrder<TWorkshop extends Workshop<TWorkshop["vehicleType"] & Vehicle>> {
  vehicle: TWorkshop["vehicleType"];
}

Or you could just use the any type to tell TS not to worry... since the constraint you're enforcing isn't particularly useful (of course TWorkshop extends Workshop<TWorkshop["vehicleType"]>, it's more or less a tautology, so you're not losing much by weakening that to any):
interface WorkOrder<TWorkshop extends Workshop<any>> {
  vehicle: TWorkshop["vehicleType"];
}

Indeed I would almost certainly use any in practice here, to avoid circularities and to indicate that I don't really care what's going on there other than it's some kind of Workshop. I wouldn't even think about trying to represent the circular self-constraint unless any had some really negative side effect.
Playground link to code

Thank you very much, this is very helpful! Not sure Why I didn't consider Workshop<any> (probably because "any is evil") but that's indeed a neat solution.

I pointed out that you can use any in my reply also. This will type TWorkshop["vehicleType"] as any within the WorkOrder type definition, so if you were to try to do any type logic within the WorkOrder type itself, you lose type safety there. However any instance of a WorkOrder involves a concrete Workshop that does not have an any, so its a very small area of weakness.

Edit: It's been pointed out that the original code did work in TS 4.7, and technically does in TS 4.8, so while the below answer gives a solution, it doesn't address that particular syntax.

interface WorkOrder<TWorkshop extends Workshop<TWorkshop["vehicleType"]>>

You are trying to use TWorkshop to constraint TWorkshop, which is cyclic and as far as I know not possible. I suspect that TS is not providing a good error message here.
Workshop is invariant - it uses TVehicle in an ordinary position, where a subclass of TVehicle is permitted, but not a superclass. It also uses TVehicle as a callback argument - a function argument must be the same or wider as the specified type - it can be a superclass but not a subclass. These two requirements mean that only a Workshop<A> can be assigned to Workshop<A>. Commonly in a situation like this the constraint would be TWorkshop extends Workshop<Vehicle>, but due to the invariance this doesn't let us use TWorkshop<Boat> and isn't useful to us.
The crude answer to invariant generics is simply to use TWorkshop extends Workshop<any>, but this introduces an unwanted any type to our system. (In some situations it is probably harmless, such as const foo = x satisfies Y<any>, here the any is only used in the satisfies check and doesn't get into the types of our values.)
Instead we can simply make TVehicle extends Vehicle our generic type for WorkOrder. In this example that is trivial, but even if we needed a Workshop we could create a suitable workshop type with Workshop<TVehicle>.
interface Vehicle {}
interface Airplane extends Vehicle {
  number: number;
}
interface Boat extends Vehicle {
  color: string;
}
interface Workshop<TVehicle extends Vehicle = Vehicle> {
  vehicleType: TVehicle;
  repair: (vehicle: TVehicle) => WorkOrder<TVehicle>;
}
interface WorkOrder<TVehicle extends Vehicle> {
  vehicle: TVehicle;
  // workshop: Workshop<TVehicle>; // for example
}

const orderA: WorkOrder<Airplane> = {
  vehicle: {
    number: 123,
  },
};

const orderB: WorkOrder<Boat> = {
  vehicle: {
    color: "blue",
  },
};

const orderC: WorkOrder<Airplane> = {
  vehicle: {
    color: "blue",
  },
};

type WorkshopAirplane = Workshop<Airplane>
// we can get the Vehicle type from a Workshop type too
const orderD: WorkOrder<WorkshopAirplane['vehicleType']> = {
  vehicle: {
    number: 123,
  },
};

TS playground link

I'll have to re re-read this tomorrow but the implied (and actual) problem is that I need to use information passed as generics to Workshop in WorkOrder and simply cannot have WorkOrder with a Vehicle generic parameter. Passing any unfortunately isn't acceptable either as I need the type information. Please note that my types, as specified, do seem to work as intended, though I'm getting the aforementioned error in TS 4.8+ (though not 4.7)

For future readers: this thread continued in the typescript discord. No new answers have been suggested there at this time.
